# Cannot connect to react app from remote host

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server

I've been having trouble trying to view a basic react app from a remote machine on the same network. Built using create-react-app. To host the app I use the following:

npm run build

serve -s build

I have opened firewalls, used different servers to serve the static files (express, python). I've tried to pass requests through nginx reverse proxy (the results for this showed the title in the tab but with a blank screen as opposed to not being able to connect at all). Here is my App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import './Components/NavBar.css'
import Comp1 from './XXXXX/XXXXX';
import Comp2 from './XXXXX/XXXXX';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>

        <div>

          <Route exact={true} path='/' render={() => (
            <div className='App'>

              <Comp1 />

            </div>
          )} />

          <Route exact={true} path='/XXXXXXX' render={() => (
            <div className='App'>

              <Comp2 />

            </div>
          )} />

        </div>

      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}
```

and package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I am able to access the app locally via localhost or ip 192.X.X.X, but cannot access from another machine on the network.

Output of "netstat -a" from powershell shows :

TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           DESKTOP-XXXXXXX:0      LISTENING

This seems like something that should work out of the box and it is incredibly frustrating. Does anyone know what is going on here?

OS = Windows 10

Comment: Note this is nothing to do with React/CRA, just how you're serving the built files.